# Replacing more than one attributes in XSLT (with identity template)

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0

Hi I have to replace more than one attributes of a given tag using XSLT while copying the entire file with identity template. With my given XSLT I'm able to replace one attribute (value of class) but not the other one.
**Input file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--OTHER STUFF-->    
  <div class="LR" id="12">
  </div>
  <!--OTHER STUFF-->
</body>
</html>
```

**Output file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--OTHER STUFF-->
  <div class="WZ" id="56">
  </div>
  <!--OTHER STUFF-->
</body>
</html>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@id='12']/@class">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">WZ</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="id">56</xsl:attribute> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanking you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try matching `@*`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@id='12']/@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">WZ</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">56</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives the desired result:

```
<div class="WZ" id="56"></div>
```

Comment: A more general solution would have been better. The problem with this is that if the div[@id=12] node has other attributes other than class and div, these attributes will be lost, which is probably not what the OP would want.

Answer (score 6):

This template also copies across any extra attributes the <div> node might have, and thus it is a more robust solution.

**This template...**

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@id='12']"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div id="56" class="WZ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="
      (@*[local-name()!='id']
         [local-name()!='class'])
      | node()"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

**...will tranform this element...**

```
<div class="LR" id="12" other="x">
```

**...into...**

```
<div id="56" class="WZ" other="x" />
```

**Notice that the extra attribute "other" is retained!**

---

### Update

More for general interest than answering the question, here is a couple of equivalent alternatives...

#### XSLT 1.0 Alternative

Here is another XSLT 1.0 template that does the same thing. It is less efficient but more concise (well, sort of)...

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@id='12']"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:attribute name="id">56</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">WZ</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

#### XSLT 2.0 Alternative

I know the OP is using XSLT 1.0. This is just for interest. Want both brevity and efficiency? Never fear! Help is here with this XSLT 2.0 alternative...

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:div[@id='12']"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <div id="56" class="WZ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@id,@class) | node()" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```